# Scrollbars no longer visible in scrollable elements in Android System Webview 55.0.2883.91 for Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, css, webview

To get scrollbars to appear in scrollable elements in a webview, such as a div, I used to use the following css styles:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

All worked fine until the latest update of Android webview, when all of a sudden the scrollbars no longer appeared. This is unacceptable for the web application I'm developing, which needs scrollbars to give the users a visual cue that there is more content if they scroll down. Does anybody know how to get the scrollbars appearing again with the lastest webview?

Answer (score 0):

I think this URL is help full

```
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
```